# Trouble setting up karma-cordova (Linux)

Tags: linux, cordova, karma-jasmine

First time doing anything on karma or linux so forgive me if I have made an obvious mistake.

Trying to run basic tests on karma-jasmine using cordova.

On karma start I get the following error logs:

`30 10 2015 17:33:28.644:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
30 10 2015 17:33:28.651:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.14 server started at http://localhost:9876/
using settings:  { platforms: [ 'android', 'ios' ],
  mode: 'emulate',
  hostip: '10.0.2.2',
  target: '0468de2a213eae29',
  plugins: [ 'org.apache.cordova.console' ] }
30 10 2015 17:33:28.654:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser undefined on Cordova
30 10 2015 17:33:28.655:ERROR [launcher]: [TypeError: Object undefined on Cordova has no method 'on']
TypeError: Object undefined on Cordova has no method 'on'
    at /home/phil/node_modules/karma/lib/launcher.js:94:17
    at next (/home/phil/node_modules/karma/node_modules/batch/index.js:118:7)
    at Batch.end (/home/phil/node_modules/karma/node_modules/batch/index.js:154:5)
    at launch (/home/phil/node_modules/karma/lib/launcher.js:110:11)
    at invoke (/home/phil/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home/phil/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:170:24)
    at Server.g (events.js:180:16)
    at Server.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at net.js:1056:10
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
[spawn] stdout: Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.console" via npm
[spawn] stdout: WARNING: org.apache.cordova.console has been renamed to cordova-plugin-console. You may not be getting the latest version! We suggest you`cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.console`and`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console`.
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.console" via cordova plugins registry
[spawn] stdout: Plugin "org.apache.cordova.console" already installed on android.
[spawn] stdout: Plugin "org.apache.cordova.console" already installed on ios.
[spawn] stderr: Platform android already added.
[spawn] stdout: WARNING: Applications for platform ios can not be built on this OS - linux.
[spawn] stderr: Platform ios already added.
Done adding platforms
[spawn] stdout: Running command: /tmp/cordova_test/platforms/android/cordova/build
[spawn] stderr: [Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.]
[spawn] stdout: ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /tmp/cordova_test/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
[spawn] stderr: Error: /tmp/cordova_test/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/root/.nvm/v0.10.40/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
30 10 2015 17:33:34.455:ERROR [launcher.cordova]: "cordova build" failed with code 1`

Below is my karma.conf.js file:

```
    module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      '*.js',
      'test/test1/test1.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preproces                                                                                                                                                             sor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WAR                                                                                                                                                             N || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file chan                                                                                                                                                             ges
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launc                                                                                                                                                             her
    browsers: ['Cordova'],

    cordovaSettings: {
        platforms:['android', 'ios'],
        mode: 'emulate',
        hostip: '10.0.2.2',
        target :'0468de2a213eae29',
        plugins: ['org.apache.cordova.console']
        },

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    plugins: [
        'karma-cordova-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-cordova-launcher'
        ],

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultanous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Any advice appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Probably not the cause of the issue but you might fix `karma-cordova-launcher` appearing twice in `plugins`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the user running karma has not set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Try opening the terminal and typing:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/your/android/sdk 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
```

You can also add those lines to the user `.bashrc` to load them in each login.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped. 
Still not 100% working but this was something that needed to be done.

Comment: If this fixed but you are getting new errors you can edit the question or add a new one, but I think that this solves the error that you are talking about in the current question based on the posted error log.

Comment: I then had to install jdk. Now I am getting an unrelated error so decided not to edit this post.
Although: where can I find the .bashrc file?